# How do friendly and enemy Ana grenade effects interact?

Tags: overwatch

Ana has a biotic grenade as one of her abilities, which gives allies a boost of health and a boost to healing for a period of time, and prevents enemies from healing at all. If I get hit by a friendly biotic grenade, immediately followed by an enemy biotic grenade, what will happen? Will the healing boost effect be negated? What about if I am hit by an enemy biotic grenade first, then a friendly biotic grenade?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The healing boost will have no effect because you have the debuff, which allows to no healing at all. However, if you're hit by the friendly grenade first, you will receive the 100 Healing. If you get hit by the enemy grenade first, the effect from the friendly one will be negated for it's duration (both the 100 initial healing and the boost).

Comment: So... if you have the debuff, the buff fails, what if you have the buff? Will the debuff work?

Comment: What this answer says: Both the buff and the debuff get applied, but when the debuff is applied it will negate the buff. The 100 healing is applied when the grenade hits. Since debuffs are not applied retroactively, you will thus get the 100 hp for getting hit by an allied grenade if it hits before the enemy grenade, because... well... that's how time works.

Comment: A percentage increase of healing on no healing is still no healing. This is a clear answer and I don't see what's so confusing.